# Spectrum view in android

Tags: android

I am developing a music player in Android and I have searched past few days an approach to make a spectrum view for the current playing song. I didn't find any libraries or ideas but I think I need to make an algorithm that analyzes the frequency of the song.

Anyone know the best approach of completing this task ?Thank you.

Comment: Search for **FFT** analysis.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it can be named like this too.

Comment: So, you did **no research** at all...

Comment: I didn't even know how it's called and a friend sayd It's named spectrum

Comment: To get the spectrum, you must use the FFT analysis.